# Can SQL Server's BCP output to multiple gzip compressed files?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, bcp

I've been looking into `bcp.exe` on SQL Server and am wondering if its abilities are limited to what the documentation actually says...

Is there no native way to output to multiple files?

And regardless of being able to output to multiple files or not, can it output to at least compressed files?

Comment: When exporting to a single file, how large can the file get? Can it ever go over 4 GB?

Answer (score 4):

Not natively with BCP, but if you define SQL Server Integration Services as native (after all, it's free in the box with SQL Server), then use SSIS instead. You can even output to compressed files with third party add-ons for SSIS.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for 3rd party add-ons? I've heard of ZappySys, but that's about it

Comment: If you google for SSIS zip, there's a bunch of options.

Comment: @BrentOzar has your answer changed since 2017 or is this still the pro advice? What are your thoughts on using xp_cmdshell and gzip something like this https://www.sqlshack.com/prepare-zip-or-rar-files-in-sql-server-using-xp_cmdshell-t-sql/

Comment: @davos given that SQL Server is licensed by the CPU core and is very, very expensive, I would not use it as a file compression tool, no. That would cause your CPU usage to get high and cause other queries to suffer. SQL Server is a relational database, not an app server.

Comment: Thanks I get your point. The use-case is for speeding up large data extraction and transfer over the internet. For example with Snowflake's snowsql tool, it will compress data prior to sending it to the remote server, and similarly exporting from DW systems like Redshift & Snowflake they will compress exported data files; I just thought you might have a good go-to option. Granted those are cloud DW's and it's probably easy to do something on Azure with SQL Database ut I am talking on-prem (well, data center) here.